# Changing Tabs CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular9

I am working on mat tab. My code is as follows:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab [label]="tab" *ngFor="let tab of lotsOfTabs">Content</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Stackblitz is located at:
https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-paginated-example.ts

https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples#tab-group-paginated

I want to change style of tabs. I want tabs to look as follows
[image: tabs]

I want tabs as shown in attached picture. Selected tab with blue background color and res tab white background and tabs connect with lines as shown in image. How can I do that?

Comment: Your stackblitz link is referencing an invalid file. can you fix it? I be glad to help!

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples#tab-group-paginated

Comment: @Don attached link for code I was trying you will get stackblitz there

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities:

You can overall create your own material theme for your angular application
(Recommending this course: https://courses.decodedfrontend.io/courses/angular-material-theming-workshop)

or overwrite the css inside your tab component with ::ng-deep

```scss
::ng-deep {
  .mat-mdc-tab-labels .mdc-tab {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid blue !important;
    margin-right: 20px !important;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: -22px;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      height: 5px;
      width: 22px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
  }
  .mdc-tab:last-child:after {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .mdc-tab-indicator--active {
    background-color: blue !important;
  }

  .mat-mdc-tab:not(.mat-mdc-tab-disabled).mdc-tab--active .mdc-tab__text-label,
  .mat-mdc-tab-link:not(.mat-mdc-tab-disabled).mdc-tab--active
    .mdc-tab__text-label {
    color: white;
  }

  .mat-mdc-tab .mdc-tab__text-label,
  .mat-mdc-tab-link .mdc-tab__text-label {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxbdcb

You should note that as angular developer we should avoid using ::ng-deep, since its deprecated in the latest versions, but still works to use if you want to bootstrap some showcase.

It's recommended to use the provided material theming api for production products for such customizations.
As I mentioned the course above, you will learn comprehensive best practice material style theming in this video (i took that course too).
You will also find similar resources for free on youtube on how material theming works in angular.
However just for demonstration purposes there is no problem for using ::ng-deep for now.

Sources:

1. https://angular.io/guide/component-styles
2. https://v7.material.angular.io/guide/theming
3. https://v7.material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components
4. https://courses.decodedfrontend.io/courses/angular-material-theming-workshop

Bare in mind that to use angular material theming you should have some understanding on the sass language (css preprocessor) to fully take advantage of the angular material theming api.